# How to import data into multiple CSV files using Python based on date

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have created the below code to import data in CSV file from PostgreSQL DB. However, I want to create multiple files based on date.

```
import psycopg2
import csv

conn_string = "host='' port='5432' user='' password='' dbname=''"

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

cur=conn.cursor()

query="select * from sample where date between '' and ''"

cur.execute(query)

title=[i[0] for i in cur.description]

result=cur.fetchall()

csvfile=open('filename.csv','w')

if result:
    c = csv.writer(csvfile)
    c.writerow(title)
    c.writerows(result)


cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The files should be split similar to the below format:

```
01jan.csv
02jan.csv 
etc.
```

Comment: In case you have only 2 dates, then you can have 2 different queries 2 fetch the result. And write each result in a different file. If you have many dates and want to create a csv for each date you should split the data you fetched from the result based on dates and then write to csv file.

Comment: How to do that? Meaning I am now putting the entire data in one file irrespective of date. But how to split the file based on date. I am stuck on how to implement the logic in this case. I am extremely new to Python so a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, in your case the result object returned should be the list of tuples. Each tuple will correspond to one row in the postgres table. Check which column is the date column and then split the result data according to date. If you can write about what data are you getting, I can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the query results and open a new file whenever the row date changes. The results must be ordered by date, otherwise you can lose some data.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import csv
import datetime

# conn_string = ...
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

# we need results in dict
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

# order by date - important!
query = "select * from sample where date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-10' order by date"
cur.execute(query)
title = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

date = None
writer = None
csvfile = None

for row in cur:
    if date != row['date']:
        # when date changes we should close current file (if opened)
        # and open a new one with name based on date
        if csvfile:
            csvfile.close()
        date = row['date']
        filename = date.strftime("%d%b")+ '.csv'
        csvfile = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(title)
    writer.writerow(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The above solution is acceptable for rather small datasets. If the amount of data for one day is large, you should rather use [`copy_expert()`](http://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert)

```
cur = conn.cursor()

# example loop for ten days of Jan 2018
for day in range(1, 10):
    date = datetime.date(2018, 1, day)
    filename = date.strftime("%d%b")+ '.csv'
    command = 'copy (select * from sample where date = %s) to stdout with csv header'
    sql = cur.mogrify(command, [date])
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
```